# Making On-Hold/Closed and How to ask information more clear?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, closed-questions, on-hold

I'm a relatively new user. I'm a reasonable person, I read needed info, I listen to commenters and tips and try to learn when possible.
One thing that bothered me in my very short "stay" here is the put-on-hold issue.

It seems from many conversations (links below) that many users, most are new like myself, have hard time understanding (or agreeing) with some rules regarding questions that are **put on hold**.

My own example - I've read the put-on-hold help section quite early after sign-up but since it's so loaded with a-lot-but-not-too-well-sorted text I've missed important information regarding it, that led me to some frustration later on.

Add to it that questions are being put on hold VERY QUICKLY it causes confusion and negative feeling to new users.

**MY SUGGESTIONS**

1. Re-write the put-on-hold page (change some text and/or its appearance).
2. Make it a top-sticky-highlighted question that will be visible only to low-rep users.
3. Add a section about on-hold/close questions and maybe how to write them (as a short to-do list) in the Tour-Page.

I do believe it's more important for new users to be aware of how to write a reasonable question and what happens when a question is being put on-hold, rather than for example know so soon about badges (they are needed, helpful, cool and fun but still..)

I also believe it'll help in making new users feel less negativity, and the community by maybe affecting the number of such questions or the time they are being kept unedited.

I'm pretty sure that on-hold questions have high % to new users, once you get the idea of what it means and especially - how to write a good question - you're OK. But as a newbie this is crucial info.

Example links that may shed some light on my question purpose:

1. [Prevent questions put on hold in the first 24-48 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268312/prevent-questions-put-on-hold-in-the-first-24-48-hours/268315#268315)
2. [Let questions stay open for a minimum amount of time before being closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10890/let-questions-stay-open-for-a-minimum-amount-of-time-before-being-closed)
3. [What is a "closed" or “on hold” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question)
4. [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users)

Comment: While I agree with the general idea of making it easier to find what this whole "on hold" means, especially for new users, I am not sure what exactly you suggest. Add *what* to the tour page, *where* exactly?

Comment: I suggest any of the points under "MY OFFER". Deciding where exactly to put it in tour-page is something admins need to carefully think about so who am I to decide. But I would put it in top area because usually people read the beginning of a long page/text more than its end. As for text editing - I can HELP with that being a typography designer but it still takes some thought!

Comment: Your first two links are not the sort of features we want to support.  Preventing moderation is the simplest method to make experts jump ship.

Comment: it's the conversations within those links that are in interest..

Answer (score 8):

No.  Adding it to the tour page does not make sense.  The tour page is already long enough that many people don't read it.  From a usability / UX perspective, being concise is essential.  The tour page should contain only the absolute minimum question necessary to begin participating.

It makes more sense to provide information on "on hold" questions when it is first relevant, not on the tour page.  This might mean, for instance, that when a user discovers that their question has been put on hold, there should be a way for the user to learn about what that means and what they can do to remedy the situation.

As far as presenting information about how to ask a good question, it makes sense to provide that information at the time when the user starts to ask their question.  The "Ask Question" page does already provide some information about how to write a reasonable question.

I think it makes more sense to look at the information provided to users when they first ask a question and/or when their question is first put on hold, and check whether that will help guide them towards contributing constructively.

TL;DR: Don't drown users in information; provide information only at the time when it becomes relevant.

Comment: Fair enough, it was just 1 offer, what about the other 2? Also be advised I'm not saying that the current on-hold auto-comment shouldn't exist. It should how ever *maybe* direct to a better written page. Or maybe make a sticky demo-question to show these things? I'm just thinking out loud how to solve something, instead of accepting the (not too good) situation as it is. According to things I've read around - I'm not the only one thinking like that.

Comment: @Yar, I suggest you develop your ideas to make them more concrete.  *"Re-write the put-on-hold page"* - How?  What should it say?  I suggest you do a bit of research, then make a more specific proposal.  "Thinking aloud" and "someone else oughta figure out how to solve this" isn't as useful as a concrete, well-thought-out proposal.  Incidentally, making 3 proposals in a single question probably makes the question too broad for this site format, since it leads exactly to the situation here (where someone provides a response to only one of them but not the others).

Comment: @Yar another option is retag this as [tag:discussion] and ask people for more ideas how to make the "on hold" more clear and visible, instead of just saying "it's not good, fix it" as you essentially doing now.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Took your tag advice. I thought it's quite basic that people who share a conversation would not only put their for/against opinion but will maybe offer something of their own. Especially more senior users (since I'm still new). That's also why I added a comment on my own qu that asks to participate, wasn't sure if it fits space in the qu itself

Comment: @D.W. Hopefully I will find some time soon to maybe create a document with the text the way I see it. I don't think though, making 3 proposals in 3 different posts is good, because it scatters things out.